# How to print full exception chain using XMLLayout

Tags: java, logback

I configured logback appender with the XMLLayout:

```
<appender name="errorFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.log4j.XMLLayout">
            <locationInfo>true</locationInfo>
        </layout> 
    </encoder> 
</appender>
```

When an exception is logged, in the resulting log4j:event tag I see only one log4j:throwable tag that corresponds to the top level exception.

Is there any way to configure logback to print the full exeption chain like in simple pattern layout?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating logback sources, it turned out that there is not any property to controll the length of the exception chain in the XMLLayout. It simply print only the top level exception.